# Switching among cli and vim and other files workflow

Tags: linux, command-line, vim, vimrc

I saw some kind of workflow in vim:
Vim had a file open. Then some combination of keys made vim disappear and the user was in the command line working in cli mode, then opened another file and then suddenly returned to the previously opened file exactly at the place/line he was.
It reminded me the switch among windows we do in Windows.
Does anyone know how this worflow is done in vim?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several options to do so:

- You can use a terminal multiplexer like [screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [tmux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux).

  In screen, for example,  the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> - <kbd>a</kbd>, has the same functiononality as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in graphical environments: switch to the last screen.
- Or you use `vim`'s internal function.

  Type `:!command` in `vim`'s command mode. For example: `:!ls -l`. After the command finishes press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to switch back to `vim`.
- There is one more option: [Job conrol](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html).

  Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to stop the current process (`vim`). You will find yourself in a terminal. To bring the stopped process back to the foreground type `fg`.

For me, I prefer screen. I have an unwritten rule for myself: "Always open a screen."

Comment: Indeed, multiplexing would explain the "sudden" return.

Comment: +1.Option `:!command` is excluded since I know about this and that was not used for sure. 1)How would you do (a) with tmux? 2) When you do `Ctrl+z` and start working in the cli can you still open vim again for other files? So the fg only would bring back the originally opened?

Comment: @Jim yes you can edit other files. You can also stop them too. In the link I provided, you see the available job control commands. With `jobs` you can display the currently stopped jobs and with `fg 1` you can bring the first of the two back to the foreground.

Comment: What is the equivalent command in tmux to the one you mention in screen?

Comment: @Jim in `tmux` the equivalent is: `ctrl-b l` see this page for comparsions: http://www.dayid.org/os/notes/tm.html

Answer (score 4):

You can press `Ctrl-z` to stop vim and go to CLI, do whatever you need to (edit another vim file perhaps), then press `fg` on command line to return back into vim at the same place you left off at. If you didn't see the command `fg` being typed, then it's very likely that [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) was being used.

Comment: After pressing `Ctrl-z` you can still open other files with vim?

Comment: @Jim yes, indeed. Though, if you open the same file, you'll get a warning about it already being edited.

Comment: Interesting question - got me wondering if there is a way to edit another file in the same instance that you just stopped (without `fg`), and it turns out you can send files for editing to that vim instance using [vim server](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5999837/2089697).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about the "suddenly returned ..." part, but the first bit is fairly trivial. The `:shell` command opens your shell. For me, it opens at wherever I was when I opened `vim`, so it is inheriting settings from `vim`, [as G-Man notes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155933/switching-among-cli-and-vim-and-other-files-workflow#comment255048_155936). That gives you the CLI mode. You can also open another `vim` from it. Quitting this shell returns you to wherever you where in `vim` originally. You can always bind a shortcut to `:shell`.

Comment: (1) `:sh` is already a shortcut to `:shell`. (2) The shell that is spawned is inheriting its working directory and other environment settings *from `vim` itself*, not from the parent shell. To demonstrate this, in `vim`, type `:cd /some/other/directory` and then `:sh`.

Comment: @G-Man shortcut as in a keybinding such as Ctrl-K or F11. But thanks for the second tip.

Comment: So if you inherit the environment from vim instead of the parent shell, is that problematic to use?

Comment: @Jim no, unless you set some environment variables in `vim` which you don't need in your shell.